# Jquery trigger function on visibility of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, bootstrap-4, visibility

What I'm aiming at is that each time the button appears an action is triggered on some items.
This is what I want to achieve:

```
$(".navbar-toggler").on(":visible", function(){..})
```

However, I can't find a function doing this exactly. Do I need a jQuery plugin?
This is my html snippet (I'm using the bootstrap navbar which hides the toggle Button at a certain viewport to enable a responsive layout) with the button I'm referring to:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navLinks" aria-label="Toggle navigation" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-navicon"></i>
    </span>
</button>
```

That's my result:

```
var elem = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 991.98px)");

function screenTest(e){
    if (e.matches) {
        $(".nav-link").removeClass("underline");
  } else {
        $(".nav-link").addClass("underline");
  }
}
elem.addEventListener("change", screenTest);
```

Comment: It is the bootstrap built-in-function that goes with their navbar which hides the toggleButton each time a certain viewport is achieved.

Comment: You could use a media query event listener https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener

Comment: @charlietfl thank you! It worked perfectly well!